# Is putting functions in classes a good practice?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, class

I'm not asking about this specific example but in general. I wonder what is better way of do it. Leave the function inside the class. Example:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        room_width = random.randint(MIN_WALL_LEN, MAX_WALL_LEN)
        room_height = random.randint(MIN_WALL_LEN, MAX_WALL_LEN)
        self.x1 = random.randint(1, WIDTH - rect_width - 1)
        self.y1 = random.randint(1, HEIGHT - rect_height - 1)
        self.x2 = self.x1 + rect_width
        self.y2 = self.y1 + rect_height

        # This function is only used for this class
        def create_walls(x1, y1, x2, y2):
            xs = range(x1, x2)
            ys = range(y1, y2)

            return [
                [(x, y1) for x in xs],          # top
                [(x1, y) for y in ys],          # left
                [(x2-1, y) for y in ys],        # right
                [(x, y2 - 1) for x in xs],      # bottom
            ]

        self.walls = create_walls(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
```

Or should I put function outside so it'll be defined only once:

```
def create_walls(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    xs = range(x1, x2)
    ys = range(y1, y2)

    return [
        [(x, y1) for x in xs],          # top
        [(x1, y) for y in ys],          # left
        [(x2-1, y) for y in ys],        # right
        [(x, y2 - 1) for x in xs],      # bottom
        ]

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        room_width = random.randint(MIN_WALL_LEN, MAX_WALL_LEN)
        room_height = random.randint(MIN_WALL_LEN, MAX_WALL_LEN)
        self.x1 = random.randint(1, WIDTH - rect_width - 1)
        self.y1 = random.randint(1, HEIGHT - rect_height - 1)
        self.x2 = self.x1 + rect_width
        self.y2 = self.y1 + rect_height

        self.walls = create_walls(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
```

Does it make any difference or I shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: Check the [staticmethod decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

Comment: `# This function is only used for this class` so this is a method of this class and should be put in that class.

Comment: That's not just in the class, it's in the method; it's *only* accessible within `__init__`.

Comment: You can make a staticmethod of it

Answer (score 2):

Putting inside __init__ like you did is pointless since you can just put the code there...

If you want to use it a few times and not only from __init__ then you can declare it as a private method

```
def _create_walls(self):
    ...
    self.walls = []
```

I would wait on putting it outside the class until another class would want to use it

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need a `self` parameter if the function is in the class (but I see you made it in the init, so nevermind)

Secondly, does that function belong to a rectangle in any way? Seems to just be a random function to generate a list of lists. In that case, personal opinion says two options:

1. leave it outside
2. Make it a static method of the class